# How can I replace this generic type with a wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I have this class

```
public static class ErrorUtils {

    public static APIError parseError(Response<LoginResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> converter =
                retrofit.responseConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);

        APIError error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new APIError();
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

I want to change the method signature of `parseError` to accept any type of `Response<>` not just `Response<LoginResponse>`

How can I do that?

EDIT: Clarification: I am reading this tutorial on Retrofit 2 error handling.
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

I want to move the ErrorUtils class to my RetrofitClient class, and out of the LoginUserRetrofitImpl class, so that I can use this error handling code in all my network request retrofit implementations.

Comment: Can't you use Response as interface? I don't see how you need generics here.

Comment: 1) What does `response.errorBody()` return? 2) What is the signature of `Converter.convert(...)`?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak yep, worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be actually using anything specific to `LoginResponse`, you could probably just change it to

```
public static APIError parseError(Response<?> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> converter =
            retrofit.responseConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);

    APIError error;

    try {
        error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new APIError();
    }

    return error;
}
```

Comment: I can accept in 4 minutes, worked this way as well. it also worked without any generic type

Comment: If you don't put a generic type, then this is "raw" usage and is discouraged; much better to have the generic wildcard there.